# javascript recursive function: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack-overflow

I have a recurent function that traverses a `ul` `li` nested hierarchy. It bubbles up from a certain **node**, until reaches the `ul` with class **tree-0** (which is the root of the hierarchy).

**The function:**

```
function setupSelectedCategory(elem) {
    if (!elem)
        return;
    if (!elem.hasClass("tree-0")) {
        if (elem.parent().prop('tagName') == 'UL') {
            var index = jQuery(elem.parent().children()).index(jQuery(elem));
            jQuery(elem.parent()).accordion({ active: index });
        }
        return setupSelectedCategory(jQuery(elem.parent()));
    } 
    return;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

I've got a stack overflow exception (at least in chrome). Maybe i'm not exiting the right way from the function? Have some ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check is faulty.. do

```
if( !elem || !elem.size() )
```

Comment: Which also means there is no ancestor with the target class.